# c# List doesn't add items

Tags: c#, list

Solution: Had multiple calls to the method and therefore had more called remove more times, than items were existing.

In my programm I need to remove Items out of a List. But once I get to the RemoveAt() command, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException and it tells me that all of my Lists have a count of 0, or in other words, are empty. But though it says they are empty, the object were created and all of the methods and events are working just fine. Here's some parts of my code:

My Lists:

```
        measure = new List<Messen>(maxAblaufe);
        steuern = new List<Steuern>(maxAblaufe);
        model = new List<Model>(maxAblaufe);

        measureReflector = new List<EventReflector>(maxAblaufe);
        steuernReflector = new List<EventReflector>(maxAblaufe);
```

Creating the Lists:

```
    if (nextSet < maxAblaufe)
        {
            neuerAblauf na = new neuerAblauf();
            na.Show();
            //if (model.Count == nextSet)
                model.Add(new Model());
            na.Model = model.ElementAt(nextSet);
            model.ElementAt(nextSet).Index = nextSet;
            na.eventStartAblauf += this.startAblauf;
        }
```

And:

```
public void startAblauf(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        EventReflector ers = new EventReflector();
        EventReflector erm = new EventReflector();
        steuernReflector.Add(ers);
        measureReflector.Add(erm);
        if (nextSet > 0)
        {
            measure.ElementAt(nextSet-1).eventNextMeasure += measureReflector.ElementAt(nextSet).reflectEvent;
            steuern.ElementAt(nextSet-1).eventNextSteuern += steuernReflector.ElementAt(nextSet).reflectEvent;
        }
        else if (nextSet == 0) {
            timingMessen.eventRefreshData += measureReflector.ElementAt(nextSet).reflectEvent;
            timingSteuerung.eventRefreshSteuerung += steuernReflector.ElementAt(nextSet).reflectEvent;
        }
        model.ElementAt(nextSet).MesstabellePath = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Privat\\MessTest\\Messung" + nextSet + ".csv";
        Messen mess = new Messen(model.ElementAt(nextSet), myPLC, 60 + nextSet * 20, measureReflector.ElementAt(nextSet));
        measure.Add(mess);
        Steuern str = new Steuern(model.ElementAt(nextSet), steuertakt, myPLC, 60 + nextSet * 20, mess, steuernReflector.ElementAt(nextSet));
        steuern.Add(str);

        steuern.ElementAt(nextSet).eventDisconnectAblauf += this.disconnectAblauf;

        nextSet++;
    }
```

The part where I (try) to delete the items is this:

```
public void disconnectAblauf(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SteuernArgs es = (SteuernArgs)e;
        int index = es.index;
        int indexbefore = index;
        indexbefore--;
        int indexafter = index;
        indexafter++;
        if (index > 0 && nextSet > (indexafter))
        {
            measure.ElementAt(indexbefore).eventNextMeasure += measureReflector.ElementAt(indexafter).reflectEvent;
            steuern.ElementAt(indexbefore).eventNextSteuern += steuernReflector.ElementAt(indexafter).reflectEvent;
        }
        else if (index == 0 && nextSet > (indexafter)) {
            timingMessen.eventRefreshData += measureReflector.ElementAt(indexafter).reflectEvent;
            timingMessen.eventRefreshData -= measureReflector.ElementAt(index).reflectEvent;
            timingSteuerung.eventRefreshSteuerung += steuernReflector.ElementAt(indexafter).reflectEvent;
            timingSteuerung.eventRefreshSteuerung -= steuernReflector.ElementAt(index).reflectEvent;
        }


        steuernReflector.RemoveAt(index);
        steuern.RemoveAt(index);
        measure.RemoveAt(index);
        measureReflector.RemoveAt(index);
        model.RemoveAt(index);
```

I already tried a lot of things so there may be some commented lines or "useless" lines, just try to ignore those, thanks!

EDIT:

Trimmed Version of the (in my opinion) relevent code:

```
measure = new List<Messen>(maxAblaufe);
        steuern = new List<Steuern>(maxAblaufe);
        model = new List<Model>(maxAblaufe);

        measureReflector = new List<EventReflector>(maxAblaufe);
        steuernReflector = new List<EventReflector>(maxAblaufe);


        EventReflector ers = new EventReflector();
        EventReflector erm = new EventReflector();
        steuernReflector.Add(ers);
        measureReflector.Add(erm);

        model.ElementAt(nextSet).MesstabellePath = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Privat\\MessTest\\Messung" + nextSet + ".csv";
        Messen mess = new Messen(model.ElementAt(nextSet), myPLC, 60 + nextSet * 20, measureReflector.ElementAt(nextSet));
        measure.Add(mess);
        Steuern str = new Steuern(model.ElementAt(nextSet), steuertakt, myPLC, 60 + nextSet * 20, mess, steuernReflector.ElementAt(nextSet));
        steuern.Add(str);

        steuernReflector.RemoveAt(index);
        steuern.RemoveAt(index);
        measure.RemoveAt(index);
        measureReflector.RemoveAt(index);
        model.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: I didn't find any `RemoveAt()` in the code you posted

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` means there is no element under such index. Debug your code and you will find out where the problem is hidden very quickly

Comment: There is alot of code here, could you try to trim it down to include only the relevant code?

Comment: Oh, my bad, i was just the following lines, edited it just now @Rafalon

Comment: Your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help! - Much easier than looking at a wall of code..

Comment: I am trying to figure it out also with debugging, but I just can't figure out what the problem is, because I just use Add, but no element appears in the List, or that's how I read it.

Comment: Just debug and check, what value you get in index? And check if lists contain records or not?

Comment: The index is just right, I've it is invoked by the element supposed to be it is 0, if it's the second it is 1 @MukeshModhvadiya

Comment: Which specific line does the error occur on?

Comment: at the first RemoveAt(), though it happens on all of the Lists, already tried to switch them around @MartinZikmund

Comment: Are your lists `static`?

Comment: the aren't, and I just tried it using statics, but it doesn't change anything @Rafalon

Comment: If you add the `static` keyword, does your problem disappear? Also, you might want to put a breakpoint on the first line `measure = new List<Messen>(maxAblaufe);` and tell us if it gets hit when you try to remove a row

Comment: I found the problem, see comments to Martin Zikmunds answer, but could you tell me how making the list static could fix the problem? just curious, never really used static, final etc or learned exactly what they do. Or if you have any good site i can get the info from, thank you anyway!

Comment: I never said it would solve the problem. I just wanted to know if your calls to `disconnectAblauf` were creating new instances of your class. If it was the case, then using `static` would have allowed you to work with the same lists even with a different instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! @Rafalon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are storing the index in the `Index` property. Suppose you have three items in the collection, and first you remove the one with index 0. This will shorten the `List` and item with `Index` property of 2 will move to index 1. This however means that if you now run the remove method, the item will no longer be on the position 2 and the attempt to access it will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: That's a good point, even though it should work at the first time the method is called, shouldn't it? But it doesn't.

Comment: It should, but it is important to note it. Instead of storing the index, you could probably use `IndexOf` on the instance to get the right index in one of the lists, which should then match all of them. Anyway - could you put breakpoint on the first `RemoveAt` line and tell us the value of `index` and the number of items in each of the collections? The problem must be there

Comment: Just found out the problem, the cycle of removing the items is taking too long, so my timing class is already invoking the method a second time (or any other wierd thing that causes the method to be called a second time) and then there are no elements left to remove ...

Comment: Still gonna mark it as an answer because you saved me from future trouble! :D